# IsEmpty returns True for both an Empty Range and a Range whose cell's content is blank, how to tell the difference?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim R1, R2, R3 as Range
Set R1 = Range("A1")
Debug.Print IsEmpty(R1), IsEmpty(R2)
' Assuming A1 is blank, both will return True
```

I need to be able to tell the difference between and uninitialized Range and a cell which is simply blank (cannot simply be ignored: for example, `CountIf` will happily count blank cells...)

Any ideas other than attempting to `On Error Resume Next` access e.g. `R.Cells`?

**EDIT**

For some reason, the last Range defined is auto-initialized to Nothing. I have more than 3 Ranges is my actual code, have added R3 in code above.

So after the `Dim`: R1 Empty, R2 Empty, R3 Nothing

Again, R2 is Empty *not* Nothing. Testing for `R2 Is Nothing` fails with error 424.

**EDIT 2**

```
Sub zero()
 Dim R1, R2, R3, R4 As Range
 Set R1 = Range("a1") ' a1 is blank
 On Error GoTo ERROR
 If R2 Is Nothing Then Debug.Print "nothing" Else Debug.Print "not nothing"
ERROR:
  Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
End Sub
```

Results in 424

**EDIT 3**

```
 Dim R1 As Range, R2 As Range, R3 As Range, R4 As Range
```

works

Comment: `If R2 Is Nothing Then`  Any object-type variable which has not been assigned will be `Nothing`

Comment: "uninitialized` ranges are `Nothing`

Comment: NO! The Range is EMPTY!  `Debug.Print R2 Is Nothing` fails with 424 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Nothing

Much like a `Long` type variable defaults to 0 until stated otherwise, a `Range` type variable defaults to `Nothing` until stated otherwise.

```
Dim R1 as Range, R2 as Range
Set R1 = Range("A1")

'Outputs
'R1 Is Nothing = FALSE
'R2 Is Nothing = TRUE
'IsBlank(R1) = TRUE/FALSE
'IsBlank(R2) = Type Mismatch Error
```

---

### Proper Variable Declaration

The above only applies to `Range` variables. You have only declared your last variable as a `Range` while the rest default to `Variant` which is the source of your second error.

---

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-variables

Comment: That is not the correct way to declare variables. When you type `r2.` the range properties are available to select. When you type `r1.` the range properties are **NOT** available because of improper declaration. Just because it works does not mean it was done the right way.

Comment: well not that much of an excel expert, thank for the info. but that does nothing for answering the actual question

Comment: I did answer your actual question. If you are getting the error you mentioned then it's not because of the bit of code you shared. The answer here shows the picture of the exact line you said error out working just fine. So, you must be asking the wrong question?

Comment: edited (see above) with a copy & paste of test for Nothing. results in 424

Comment: Your issue is because you are NOT declaring the variables right. Fix that and then re-run your code lol Never had to convince someone to take the help they have asked for here before. This is a new experience for me

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a range in VBA the object variable `Is Nothing`. However, if you declare a variable as variant `IsEmpty` returns False (although nothing was assigned to it) and `Is Nothing` returns an error.

Your statement that `Dim R1, R2 As Range` "works fine" contains qualified truth. A variant can be assigned any data type, even an object, but it can't take a range's properties before a range is assigned to it. It's better to declare variables as what they are.

It seems that `IsEmpty` returns the expected result only if applied to a single cell but is always False for a range of cells. I avoid `IsEmpty` in my programming, frankly, because I never learned the intricacies involved. I use the `Len()` function for individual cells, sometimes in conjunction with `Trim()`, and `WorksheetFunction.CountA()` if I want to know if a range of cells is blank.